# how to verify that if $X$ is the lexicographically ordered square is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

show that the ordered square is locally connected but not locally path connected. what are the path components of this space?

as  i  got  the answer  here,,but i have  some confusion  in my mind..(underline in red line)

[show that the ordered square is locally connected~](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340901/show-that-the-ordered-square-is-locally-connected)

[image]

im  confusion that  that  how  can $[0,1] $ is homeormorphics  to $[0,1] \times  [0,1]$..??..as  if we  remove one point from [0,1]  it will not connected   but if we removed one point from order square  it will remain  connected.....now  my confusion is  that how  to verify that if $X$ is the lexicographically ordered square, then the map

$$\varphi:R\to X:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\langle h(x),y\rangle$$

is a homeomorphism.

Pliz help me,,,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4280/henno-brandsma.....help me

Comment: Removing a point from any connected linearly order set will render it disconnected. This also holds for the lexicographically ordered square!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it doesn't claim that $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $([0,1]\times [0,1], \mathcal{T}(<_{\text{lex}}))$. What *is* true is that $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to a "stalk" $\{t\} \times [0,1]$ in that square, for any fixed $t$; the obvious map $x \to (t,x)$ is an order preserving bijection between these sets and hence a homeomorphism.

The crucial fact about the square is that there can be no continuous path from $(a,x)$ to $(b,y)$ if $a \neq b$ and so the stalks (being path-connected as homeomorphic copies of $[0,1]$) are the path-components.

Comment: thanks  u @Henno Brandsma sir

Comment: @  henno sir   pliz give me any hints/solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944730/product-topology-vs-cofinite-topology