# Product topology Vs cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

let  $X$ denote the $\mathbb{R^2}$  endowed with the usual topology .let Y denote $\mathbb{R}$ endowed  with cofinite  topology . if Z is the product topology  space $Y \times Y$,then

a) the topology of  X is the same  as the topology  of Z

b) the topology of X is strictly coarser (weaker) than that of Z

c) the topology of Z is strictly coarser (weaker ) than that of X

d) the topology of X can not be compared  with that of Z

My attempts : I thinks  option  option d)  will correct  as X is infinite and Y is finite

im just  used  my logics  that  infinite  can not be compared  with finite

Am i right or wrong

pliz verified

thanks u

Comment: you meant $X\times Y$ instead of $Y\times Y$ ?

Comment: @Isabella see  Question no : $35$    $Y \times Y$.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vH5wsrei13Hw3lK3yn6jlgC437tVE1is/view

Comment: You're right, actually is option d. But I can't follow your argument. I would use the definition of weaker (stronger) topology: $\mathfrak T_1\subset\mathfrak T_2$. Now find open sets that are in $X$ but not in $Y\times Y$ and vice versa.

Comment: Jasmine, actually your reasoning is wrong: $Y=\mathbb{R}$ is not finite, nor is the cofinite topology a finite subset of the power set of $\mathbb{R}$, if you meant that.

Comment: It may be useful to point out explicitly that $X$ and $Y\times Y$ have the same set of points. So it at least makes sense to compare their topologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $X$ and $Z$ are $\mathbb{R}^2$ as sets. Very infinite, so I don't get your remark.

$X$ is the product topology of $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_e)$ with itself. $\mathcal{T}_e$ is the usual Euclidean topology on the reals.

It's clear that $\mathcal{T}_{\text{cof}} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_e$, as a metric topology is $T_1$, and strictly so.

So the topology on $Z$ is coarser (strictly) than that on $X$., so option c.

Comment: thanks u henno sir